# python pandas-possible to compare 3 dfs of same shape using where(max())? is this a masking issue?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, max, where-clause

I have a dict containing 3 dataframes of identical shape. I would like to create:

1. a 4th dataframe which identifies the largest value from the original 3 at each coordinate - so dic['four'].ix[0,'A'] = MAX( dic['one'].ix[0,'A'], dic['two'].ix[0,'A'], dic['three'].ix[0,'A'] )
2. a 5th with the second largest value

   ```
   dic = {}
   for i in ['one','two','three']:
       dic[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
   ```

I cannot figure out how to use .where() to compare the original 3 dfs. Looping through would be inefficient for ultimate data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider the `dict` `dfs` which is a dictionary of `pd.DataFrame`s

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
dfs = dict(
    one=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (5, 5))),
    two=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (5, 5))),
    three=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (5, 5))),
)
```

the best way to handle this is with a `pd.Panel` object, which is the higher dimensional object analogous to `pd.DataFrame`.

```
p = pd.Panel(dfs)
```

then the answers you need are very straighforward

***max***
`p.max(axis='items')` or `p.max(0)`

***penultimate***
`p.apply(lambda x: np.sort(x)[-2], axis=0)`

Comment: great answer, thanks pi. do you find any performance differences between working with panels vs. dicts of dfs ?

Comment: @MJS yes!  Working with panels will be faster.  You can quicken this up further by operating on the underlying numpy arrays.  But I'll leave that for you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st question is easy to answer, you could use the `numpy.maximum()` function to find the element wise maximum value in each cell, across multiple dataframes

```
dic ['four'] = pd.DataFrame(np.maximum(dic['one'].values,dic['two'].values,dic['three'].values),columns = list('ABC'))
```