# python pandas - identify row of rolling maximum value from panel?

Tags: python, pandas, max, panel, vectorization

Does Panel have anything like pan.idxmax(axis='items') which could return the row # or index for the largest value as in the question linked below which piRSquared answered perfectly?

[Link to original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000718/python-pandas-possible-to-compare-3-dfs-of-same-shape-using-wheremax-is-thi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the `pd.Panel` `p`

```
dfs = dict(
    one=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (5, 5))),
    two=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (5, 5))),
    three=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (5, 5))),
)

p = pd.Panel(dfs)
p.to_frame().unstack()
```

[image]

---

the `pd.Panel` object doesn't have an `idxmax` method.  But the underlying numpy array does have the `argmax` method.  I've built this custom function to leverage that.

```
def idxmax(pn, axis=0):
    indices = pd.Series(['items', 'major_axis', 'minor_axis'])
    idx, col = indices.drop(axis)
    return pd.DataFrame(pn.values.argmax(axis),
                        pn.__getattribute__(idx),
                        pn.__getattribute__(col))
```

---

***usage***

```
idxmax(p, 0)
```

[image]

```
idxmax(p, 1)
```

[image]

```
idxmax(p, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: nicely done, pi. thanks a ton. if you were going to try to replace the item # with the item name, would you map back to the name with a dict?

Comment: @MJS something like that, yes.